# Android chat server

Tags: android

I need to create a chat/communication server for android based clients.

The android chat clients will be connected to internet via 3g or wifi network
I need following simple features

- register a new user
- send messages from one client to another
- will have roughly 500 clients connected at a time

Coming from desktop app development, I only have socket based solution in my mind and that the server should be a java based application

So the question is : Is the socket based approach workable or should I use some other communication protocol.

Answer (score 6):

While using TCP sockets will do the job, it's not a good idea as you would have to take care of a LOT of stuff, like message formatting, streaming, etc. Use one of the already available messaging protocols and libraries.

I would suggest looking into [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol), which has a set of open standards for implementing messaging between devices. An advantage is that there are plenty of libraries available for implementing both XMPP clients and servers.

For implementing an XMPP client on Android devices, you can use a library called [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/). It is actually a Java based library. I have implemented a Facebook XMPP chat client using [Asmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/), which is a Android port of Smack. The Smack documentation is applicable to Asmack as well. However, Asmack hasn't been updated for two years and has some issues and I've been thinking of changing my client to Smack to see if the new version plays nice with Android.

As for implementing an XMPP server, you can check out [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp), made by the same guys who made Smack. I have not used this yet, but the project page has extensive documentation on setting up Openfire. Judging by the quality of the Smack library which I used, I daresay Openfire will work pretty well.

Good luck!

Comment: Additionally you should consider how your application is using the network from both a performance point of view but also battery life and how much of your customer's data you are using. There are some articles here about this here http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=7200042 and you can also use the ARO tool on Android to see how well your app is doing http://developer.att.com/aro

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what the other end of the server is written in, as HTTP is a high level protocol.  In reality you will probably end up using sockets, unless you do something about [GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html).  Sockets are heavyweight battery wise, and you'll probably only want to keep the socket around once in a while to check for updates on the chat server at some rate proportional to the app's use.  Please also remember that you cannot keep the network connection on the main thread, and it will typically be accessed through a Service.