# Chat application - which tech is better to implement chat app in Android 

Tags: java, android, web-services, sockets, websocket

**I have to make an android application which is basically a chat application.**In this chat app the user can interact with single user as well in a group that means Group chat is also there. I am using php as the back end for database . I have never done this type of work earlier so need some suggestions or guidance.

```
The options i have seen is as follow :

1. Web-services 

2. Socket Programming 

3. XMPP using the smack api
```

Now i am confused in them that which is better to implement chat feature in android. Also i didn't get any sample code for that. One of my team member is asking me to use the socket programming but i didn't get any sample app or anything for socket programming in android. I don't know socket programming this time. How we can connect the our phone to the server and then some other device. Hope you get me what i want to Conway you.

So can any one please guide me and show me the right direction to move on. Also if you can provide me any sample code, that can be really helpful. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Check my answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667918/android-chat-server/12668572#12668572)

Comment: @VinaySShenoy do you have any idea about to use sockets in android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option (besides XMPP, which is certainly a valid approach for chat, since it was designed for that) would be using WebSocket. Using WebSocket would open the possiblity of having a pure browser client as well.

For WebSocket on Android, there is AutobahnAndroid, part of the [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/) family of WebSocket and WAMP implementations.

[WAMP](http://wamp.ws) is a RPC and PubSub over WebSocket protocol with multiple implementations. There is also a PHP implementation of WebSocket/WAMP: [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/).

Disclaimer: I am author of Autobahn/WAMP and work for Tavendo.

Comment: Thanks oberstet i also want to use the websocket. So i will try to implement what you have given to me. In case of any problem i will tell you

Comment: Here is an example to get you running with AutobahnAndroid and PubSub: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/tree/master/Demo/SimplePubSub

Comment: that code is to set up a connection between the server and the app but no chat feature is implemented in this

Comment: Thats trivial to do on top of PubSub (subscribe, publish, unsubscribe), which the code shows.

Comment: Thanks Oberstet for your response and help. Your invention of using the websocket by Autobhan Project is really helpful. I appreciate your hard work.

Comment: Do you have autobhan for ios also in the same way as in android ?

Comment: You can reach me by mail under: tobias dot oberstein at tavendo dot de

Answer (score 4):

For a basic Socket programming tutorial, you can check [HERE](http://ramenboy.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-sockets.html) and [HERE](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/socket-programming/).

However, I suggest using XMPP, as I have mentioned [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667918/android-chat-server/12668572#12668572), as it is a protocol designed from the ground up to be used for Messaging.